# Microsoft Graph C# SDK, Date Range

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-sdks

Just started having to learn Microsoft.Graph SDK C#. I am getting it to work however I am running in to an issue and cant seem to find the correct documentation for using this in C#

I am trying to get a week worth of event date.

```
 var filterString = $"start ge 2023-01-09& lt eq 2023-01-16";
        var events = await graphServiceClient.Me.Calendar.Events
            .Request().Filter(filterString)
            .GetAsync();
        ResultText.Text = "";
        foreach (var response in events)
        {
            ResultText.Text += response.Subject;
            ResultText.Text += Environment.NewLine;




        }
```

However, I am receiving the following in Chrome and trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. Perhaps I could not locate the correct documentation for this. Most is for the Rest API and no the C# SDK I have tried using the rest $filter and to no avail.

Code: BadRequest
Message: Invalid filter clause
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2023-01-09T19:50:50
request-id: 427f24b9-62ab-4541-bc4e-a49e02bcc508
client-request-id: 427f24b9-62ab-4541-bc4e-a49e02bcc508
ClientRequestId: 427f24b9-62ab-4541-bc4e-a49e02bcc508

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start` property is of type [dateTimeTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0) with the property `dateTime` of type `string`.

You need to filter by `start/dateTime`

```
// filter events between 2023-01-09 and 2023-01-16
var filterString = "start/dateTime ge '2023-01-09T08:00' and start/dateTime le '2023-01-16T08:00'";
var events = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Events
    .Request()
    .Filter(filterString)
    .GetAsync();
```

Supported operators for `dateTime` are less than (`lt`), greater than (`gt`), less than or equal to (`le`) and greater than or equal to (`ge`).

Documentation:

[$filter query operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=http#examples-using-the-filter-query-operator)